# Population model approximation

Tags: mathematical-modeling

The model we are using is $\frac{dp}{dt} = KP(P-M)$. Determine when P=75.

Given a table of years and the populations during those years. Specifically focusing on $1925$ and $1975$ with an h value of 1. Where the respective populations are $25$ and $47.54$. Its growing

Told to use the formula:

$P'(t) = \frac{P(t+h)-P(t-h)}{2h}$ with a step size $h =1$

to approximate $P'(t)$ where  $t=1925$ and $t=1975$ I get $P'(25)= .19$ and $P'(75)=.25$

Now plugging those in to get K and M values is a problem

$$P'(75)=KP(P-M)$$
$$.25 =K47.54(47.54-M)$$

Assuming that 47.54K is the same thing as K so it gets absorbed.

$$k = \frac{.25}{47.54-M}$$

Now plugging $K$ back into our population model.

$$.19 = \frac{.25}{47.54-M}(25)(25-M)$$

After doing algebra I get

$$M=37.385$$ but the book says that $M=100$

Comment: Why did you write $ P(75) = 0.25 $ and then plugged in $ 0.25 $ for $ P'(75) $ in the next equation?

Comment: that was an error. I adjusted it

Comment: Its supposed to be M

Comment: You switched from $ P - M $ to $ M - P $.  Ordinarily, people use the latter.

Comment: Oh boy I need to change that

Comment: Okay I will do that I understand

Answer (score 1):

Well..., you made some kind of algebra/arithmetic mistake because:
[image]

Comment: Do you see where it is?

Comment: No, and that's not really what math stack exchange is for.